# Google Maps, need to display country in TextView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, textview

i'm new to google maps and need to display the users country in a textView.
At the moment my app is displaying Latitude, Longitude and address..now I need the Country.

I have declared the following:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location myLocation;
```

And under OnCreate

```
lblAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
```

To get the Address I used;

```
private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE, int x)
{
    String strAdd = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try
    {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
        if (addresses != null)
        {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");


            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
            {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        lblAddress.setText("Your address cannot be determined");
    }
    return strAdd;
}
```

Now how do I get the country in the same way?

Comment: `returnedAddress.getCountryName()`

Comment: Could you elaborate? Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the Address, you can just call the [getCountryName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getCountryName()) method on it.

What I would do is create a POJO class so that you can return both the Address and Country from the method:

```
class MyLocation {
    public String address;
    public String country;
}
```

Then, make your method call return an instance of `MyLocation`, and populate both the Address and the Country before returning:

```
private MyLocation getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE, int x)
{
    String strAdd = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(); //added
    try
    {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
        if (addresses != null)
        {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
            myLocation.country = returnedAddress.getCountryName(); //added

            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
            {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            myLocation.address = strAdd; //added

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        lblAddress.setText("Your address cannot be determined");
    }
    return myLocation; //modified
}
```

Be sure to do null checks on the return values.

```
    MyLocation loc = getCompleteAddressString(lat, lon, x);
    if (loc.address != null) {
        //use to populate Address TextView
    }
    if (loc.country != null) {
        //use to populate Country TextView
    }
```

Comment: String strAdd = getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude, 1); - this section above got error'd when I made the suggested changes.

Comment: You need to assign the return value to a MyLocation instance, look at the last code block.